# What is the universal name for this cable and where can I get PCB connectors for them?

Tags: connector, cables, identification

What is the name for this style cable? I've always known them as nano-cables or micro-cables but I've seen them called sensor-link cables too.

[image: Cable]

I typically get the cable from [here](http://www.mcmaster.com/#sensor-cable/=jfk945). However, I don't know that this is a standard name for this cable.

Regardless, what I am really after is a source for a PCB mount connector for this style cable. Having the correct name would help my searching.

Comment: Board mount, rugged, waterproof, cheap are hard to say in same sentence. What are your criteria?

Answer (score 2):

It's more commonly known as an M12 connector.  They're industrial connectors used for remote sensors or ethernet.  There are a bunch of people that make them. There are smaller versions too, the M8 series.

Several companies make them.

http://www.te.com/catalog/minf/en/856

http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?key=brad_m12_product_families&channel=products

For some product page links.  Binder USA also makes them, and a number of other industrial manufacturers.

You can also find them from distributors like Digikey and Mouser. (Just search M12)

As long as they're the same number of poles and have the same keying, they should fit.  I'd order a sample from Molex or TE and double check.

I would stress relieve the connector if you're doing a PCB mount, the mating force for these is pretty high.  All the PCB connectors I've seen are panel mount.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to directly mount the mating connector for these cables to a PC board. You would be much better off using one of these panel mount types:

[image]

[image]

...from the same McMaster-Carr web page that you linked to. These can mount to the enclosure wall of your device where the retention against cable strain is far superior. Take the discrete wire harness on the back of the bulkhead connector, cut to necessary length and affix another type of standard PC board connector on the end to mate with your circuit board inside the enclosure.

http://www.mcmaster.com/#sensor-cable/=jfkkzt

http://www.mcmaster.com/#sensor-cable/=jfklm5

Comment: Perhaps that's why I can't find any PCB connectors.

Comment: @michael -- Great find, but McMaster is fairly feeble as far as getting information goest-- you can't even get a manufacturers name, let alone a manufacturers part number!

Comment: @ScottSeidman while McMaster hides where to buy them, they do make a great tool for learning the nomenclature to then search and find elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/314442.pdf  -- I think they may be part of the Tyco series starting at page 5012

Answer (score 0):

I was just recently was searching for a very similar part. I was told the part I was looking for was [Alectron JR-2731-3P](http://www.alliedelec.com/search/productdetail.aspx?SKU=70020803).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a PCB connector though...

Comment: Yeah I know, but if you were just looking for the name or style of connector you could maybe do a search for similar connectors that were PCB mount. I think searching for "circular DIN connector" may return useful results.